# Extract json string array value from json object using java

Tags: java, spring-boot

From below json object i have to extract the **errorSummary** with in **errorCauses** using java. i have attached the sample code which i am using in that i am getting a json exception error.

```
{
    "errorCode": "xxxx",
    "errorSummary": "xxxxxx",
    "errorLink": "xxxx",
    "errorId": "xxxxx",
    "errorCauses": [
        {
            "errorSummary": "Get the error summary"
        }
    ]
}
```

i am using below code to extract the errorCause but it's throwing error.

```
public String getExceptionMessage(MyRestTemplateException ex) {
        try {
            String Json = ex.getMessage();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Json);
            JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
            // String ExceptonMsg = json.getString("errorSummary");

            JSONObject errCause = new JSONObject(json.getString("errorCauses"));

            LOGGER.info("jsonArr AES " +errCause.toString());

            return errCause.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while get exception message: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Could some one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: if u using spring-boot then why not try with`JsonNode`

Comment: Thanks for the idea it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
            JSONObject errCause = new JSONObject(json.getString("errorCauses"));
```

with

```
            JSONObject errCause = jsonObj.getJSONArray("errorCauses");
```